# I want to set checkbox to true based on a condition in ag-grid

Tags: checkbox, angular7, ag-grid

I have a button which basically imports some data. This imported data needs to be compared with the data inside already loaded ag-grid and if there is a match, set the cehckbox of that particlar row node to  true.

This is the button which checks for the condition:

```
    enableCheck() {
    alert('works');
    if (this.DataService.isNotBlank(this.rowDataImport)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.rowDataImport.length; i++) {
            if (this.DataService.isNotBlank(this.rowData)) { 
                for (let j = 0; j < this.rowData.length; j++) { 
                    if (this.DataService.isNotBlank(this.rowData[j].calDate)) {
                        for (const calDates of this.rowData[j].calDate) {
                            if (
                            this.rowDataImport[i].isin === calDates.isin ||
                            this.rowDataImport[i].portfolioName === calDates.portfolioName ||
                            this.rowDataImport[i].valuationDate === calDates.valuationDate
                                ) 
                                {
                                     // alert('true')
                                    this.checkValue = true;
                                } else {
                                    this.checkValue = false;                                        
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }

}
```

The this.checkValue is a flag which will be true if match is found.

```
  public gridColumnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: 'Portfolio Name',
            field: 'portfolioName',
            cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
            headerCheckboxSelection: true,
            headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
            checkboxSelection: true,
            pinned: 'left',
            filter: true,
            cellRendererParams:(params) => {
                console.log(params);
                if (this.checkValue) {
                 params.node.selected = true;
                }
            }
        },
]
```

here I used cellRendererParams. But this will only for on load I guess. What to do if I want to update the ag-grid row from a value outside i.e. from import check as given above?

Comment: have you tried api.refreshCells() once import is done? and to add you need the else condition to send params.node.selected = false

Comment: yes, I tried setRowData method. It didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should add id for each row in `defaultColDef`

```
this.defaultColDef = {
  getRowNodeId: data => data.id,
};
```

Then you can find this id and set the checkbox to true.

Also, you can find separate field by name.
It is really easy, you should use the next combination

```
  selectRow() {
    this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
        if (node.id == 1 || node.id == 2 || node.data.country == 'Australia') {
            node.setSelected(true);
        }
    });
  }
```

Working example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ijgg6bXVleOAmNL8

In this example when we click on the button -  we set the checkbox to true for two rows with id 1 and 2 and for each field that has country 'Australia'

And in your case, you are using incorrect configuration.

You should you `cellRenderer`

```
cellRenderer: params => {
  if(params.value === 'Ireland') {
    params.node.setSelected(true)
  }
  return params.value
},
```

One more example: https://plnkr.co/edit/PcBklnJVT2NsNbm6?preview

Answer (score 0):

I manpulated a bit and did the below which worked like a charm.

```
 this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
                    if (node.data.isin === this.rowDataImport[i].isin &&
                            node.data.portfolioName === this.rowDataImport[i].portfolioName &&
                            node.data.valuationDate === this.rowDataImport[i].valuationDate
                    ) {
                        node.setSelected(true);
                    }
```